# Is it possible to add custom commands to tmux?

Tags: tmux

I have some commands in mind that I don't want to create keybinds for and would prefer to use command mode for them. For example, I want something like:

```
<C-a>:restart-guard
```

That I can have run a script to run some commands in my guard window

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't define user defined commands directly
But you can always call a tmux script with **so** (shortest alias of **source-file**) or a program with **ru** (shortest alias of **run-shell**)

For **so**, you need to give the path to the command or to have the tmux server to start in the folder where your custom commands are

Here is a simple example, you put your restart-guard script in ~/.tmux/commands
you start tmux using a scipt :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/.tmux/commands
tmux
```

then inside tmux, do

```
<C-a>:so restart-guard
```

*I am currently looking for a way to have the directory where you started tmux and not the ~/.tmux/commands directory when starting*

Comment: Very nice! I'll be using this for sure

Comment: this trick doesn't seem to be working for me. (tmux 2.3 on ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

That is unfortunately not possible with tmux at this moment.